# LocalFolder vs LocalSettings

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

Based on the information at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData

> LocalFolder is the root folder in the local app data store and this
>   folder is backed up to the cloud.
>
> LocalSettings is the application settings container in the local app
>   data store.

I'd like to know if LocalSettings is also backed up to the cloud so my users settings will be restored if they uninstall and reinstall the app, or would I be better off making my own settings file in LocalFolder?

Thanks in advance,

Stu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally *local* data exists along with the app, however if the user activates *App Data Backup* then they can be backed up to the cloud and then used for reseting the device ([here is a very good description of local/cache/temporary](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/10/getting-started-storing-app-data-locally/)):

> During a device backup operation, the system will grab any app data in Local and store it as part of a device backup image in OneDrive. If the user resets or replaces the device, he or she will be given the choice to restore a previous backup, which will restore the app data in Local as part of the app’s installation. Note that by not storing data in Local you will effectively be opting out of backup for your app.

AFAIK the above is only for device restoration/replacement. When you uninstall and install the app, the *Local* data won't be there.

Comment: So as in that link:

`Local can contain both files (LocalFolder) and settings (LocalSettings) and should be used for any information that is of user value and can’t easily be recreated or downloaded. Data stored in Local can be backed up by the system if the device supports App Data Backup. Because of this, you should avoid using Local to store cached or temporary files that you could create or fetch again on demand.`

Therefore LocalSettings is in Local and will be included in the backup

Comment: @StuAyton Yes - *LocalSettings* should be included in the backup, however note that this is not a backup, which user can use on demand after application reinstall.

Comment: that's fine, I realise how the backup is used just wasn't sure if LocalSettings was included with LocalFolder as the main documentation wasn't explicit about it. Thanks :)